# What is the winning move here and why?

Tags: tactics

```
B1b2rk1/p3pp1p/6p1/q1Pp4/3b1B2/2n4P/P2Q1PP1/2R1K2R b K - 0 17
```

Stockfish rates this position as -2.94, so Black is clearly winning. Or is it so clear? After 1... Bxf2+ 2. Qxf2 Ne4+ 3. Bd2 Nxf2 4. Bxa5 Nxh1 5. Bxd5, White obtains the Bishop pair in an open position and a passed pawn. This is not the winning move. (Actually, there are two: The alternative is 1... Qxc5.)

However, I cannot fathom how Black is better. Sure, material is even in terms of points, the White LSB is locked in and eventually Ba6 will be played, but when is *eventually* and how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Bxf2+` gives away all your advantage because of the precise line you mention. The correct move is `e5` (to protect your bishop with tempo, note `1...e5 2.O-O exf4 3.Qxd4` doesn't work because of `Ne2+` fork), followed by `Ba6`, preventing castling and attacking the trapped `a8` bishop. Notice `Bc6-Bd7-Bg4` doesn't really save the bishop as shown below: (covering some side-variations as well, rather called for as it's a very concrete position)

```
 [title "1...e5"]
 [fen "B1b2rk1/p3pp1p/6p1/q1Pp4/3b1B2/2n4P/P2Q1PP1/2R1K2R b KQq - 0 1"]

 1...e5 (1...Qxc5 {also a good move with similar threats except the queen discovery} 2.O-O Ba6 3.Rfe1 Rxa8 4.Be3 Bxe3 5.Rxe3 d4 {easily winning: two pieces and a pawn for the rook, together with a passed pawn and dominant knight}) (1...Ba6 {The immediate Ba6 is not good enough probably but it's a fun line, the idea with Ne2+ forking bishop and knight while still taking on a8.} 2.Qxd4 Ne2+ 3.Qd2 Qxd2+ 4.Kxd2 Rxa8 5.Be3 Nxc1 6.Rxc1 {still a pawn up but it's opposite colored-bishop so always big drawing chances.}) 2.Bh6 Ba6 3.Bc6 (3.Bxd5 Rd8 4.Bf3 Bxf2+ {wins on the spot for black}) (3.Bxf8 Bxf2+ {however white recaptures loses on the spot} 4.Kxf2 Ne4+) Rc8 4.Bd7 Rxc5 5.Bg4 Bxf2+ 6.Qxf2 Ne4+ {and you're winning the house.}
```

Comment: We protect our bishop with tempo, but then what are the following ideas?

Comment: I've shown the main variation in the diagram. You keep the king in center, you take the trapped `a8` bishop, you have huge central space with two active minor pieces + a pawn for white's out of play rook on `h1,` so white's clearly losing. This position is not so much about ideas but concrete assessment in order to convert black's advantage, hence the diagram and discussion of side-lines.

Comment: A sideline to add is 3.Bxf8 (by far the most natural move) which loses to the same 3...Bxf2!

Comment: @Evargalo Yes indeed, added.